# How can this R data.table join+group+summarise, operation be made a lot faster?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

### Summary of real-world problem

Essentially this is a scenario evaluation, of a linear system of equations.
I have two data tables.

- s_dt contains the scenarios, drivers (*d*) and values (*v*) for each observed scenario (*o*).
- c_dt contains a series of terms (*n*) for a number of fitted model bases (*b*). 
  The individual powers of drivers, and associated coefficients are coded into (*d* and *t*) as name-value pairs. 
  Each basis (*b*) is essentially a polynomial with n terms.

### The issue

Repro case below gives desired output format.
But is far too slow for required use case, even on a cut-down problem.
Numbers are junk, but I can't share actual data. Running on real-world data gives similar timing.

Circa 3sec for "lil" problem on my system (12 threads).
But "big" problem is 4000 times larger. So expect circa 3hours. **Ouch!**
**Aim is to have the "big" problem run sub 5min (or ideally much faster!)**

So, awesome clever people, how can this be made a **lot** faster?
(And what is the root cause of the slowdown?)

I'll happily accept base/tidyverse solutions too, if they meet the performance needs. I just assumed data.table was the best way to go for the size of the problem.

### Current solution

Run `fun` on *s_dt*, grouping by *o*.
`fun`: Joins *c_dt* with each group data, to populate *v*, thus enabling calculation of *r* (the result of evaluating each of the polynomial equations).

In `data.table` parlance:

```
s_dt[, fun(.SD), keyby = .(o)]
```

### Repro case

- Creates two data.tables that have the combinations and field types matching real-world problem.
  But with cut-down size for illustrative purposes.
- Defines `fun`, then runs to populate *r* for all scenarios.

```
library(data.table)

# problem sizing ----
dims <- list(o = 50000, d = 50, b = 250, n = 200) # "big" problem - real-life size
dims <- list(o =   100, d = 50, b =  25, n = 200) # "lil" problem (make runtime shorter as example)

# build some test data tables ----
build_s <- function() {
  o <- seq_len(dims$o)
  d <- paste0("d",seq_len(dims$d))
  v <- as.double(seq_len(dims$o * dims$d))/10000
  CJ(o, d)[, `:=`(v = v)]
}
s_dt <- build_s()

build_c <- function() {
  b <- paste0("c", seq_len(dims$b))
  n <- seq_len(dims$n)
  d <- c("c", paste0("d", seq_len(dims$d)))
  t <- as.double(rep_len(0:6, dims$b * dims$n * (dims$d+1)))
  dt <- CJ(d, b, n)[, `:=`(t = t)]
  dt <- dt[t != 0]
}
c_dt <- build_c()

# define fun and evaluate ---- 
# (this is what needs optimising)
profvis::profvis({
  fun <- function(dt) {
    # don't use chaining here, for more useful profvis output
    dt <- dt[c_dt, on = .(d)]
    dt <- dt[, r := fcase(d == "c", t,
                          is.na(v), 0,
                          rep(TRUE, .N), v^t)]
    dt <- dt[, .(r = prod(r)), keyby = .(b, n)]
    dt <- dt[, .(r = sum(r)),  keyby = .(b)]
  }
  res <- s_dt[, fun(.SD), keyby = .(o)]
})
```

### Example inputs and outputs

```
> res
        o   b            r
   1:   1  c1 0.000000e+00
   2:   1 c10 0.000000e+00
   3:   1 c11 0.000000e+00
   4:   1 c12 0.000000e+00
   5:   1 c13 0.000000e+00
  ---                     
2496: 100  c5 6.836792e-43
2497: 100  c6 6.629646e-43
2498: 100  c7 6.840915e-43
2499: 100  c8 6.624668e-43
2500: 100  c9 6.842608e-43

> s_dt
        o   d      v
   1:   1  d1 0.0001
   2:   1 d10 0.0002
   3:   1 d11 0.0003
   4:   1 d12 0.0004
   5:   1 d13 0.0005
  ---               
4996: 100 d50 0.4996
4997: 100  d6 0.4997
4998: 100  d7 0.4998
4999: 100  d8 0.4999
5000: 100  d9 0.5000

> c_dt
         d  b   n t
     1:  c c1   2 1
     2:  c c1   3 2
     3:  c c1   4 3
     4:  c c1   5 4
     5:  c c1   6 5
    ---            
218567: d9 c9 195 5
218568: d9 c9 196 6
218569: d9 c9 198 1
218570: d9 c9 199 2
218571: d9 c9 200 3
```

Comment: You may have to check `collapse` as it may improve the performance.  Or other option would be python polars which is fast for grouping as it is based on Rust

Comment: To clarify, only the part within the `profvis` call needs to be optimized, right? The first two parts are only data creation?

Comment: Yes @Cole, just the profvis part. the rest is indeed just building some test data, so that it's a runnable example.

Comment: Within the function, we filter `t!=0`. Are we able to do that ahead of time? Since that is defined within `c_dt`, that means we could filter ahead of time so we don't have to do that filter each time. On the smaller example, that filtering is non-trivial amount of the total time.

Comment: @Cole: Yes. good spot. Filter can be done earlier. 
But I don't see a big speed increase from doing so in my profiling output.
I'll update the repro, so you can see same profiling output I do...

Comment: Is the real world data or models made using `CJ` at all? Or is that solely for illustration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be difficult to fully vectorize. The "big" problem requires so many operations that going parallel is probably the most straightforward way to get to ~5 minutes.

But first, we can get a ~3x speed boost by using `RcppArmadillo` for the product and sum calculations instead of data.table's grouping operations.

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "std::vector<double> sumprod(arma::cube& a) {
  for(unsigned int i = 1; i < a.n_slices; i++) a.slice(0) %= a.slice(i);
  return(as<std::vector<double>>(wrap(sum(a.slice(0), 0))));
}",
  depends = "RcppArmadillo",
  plugins = "cpp11"
)

cl <- makeForkCluster(detectCores() - 1L)
```

The following approach requires extensive preprocessing. The upshot is that it makes it trivial to parallelize. However, it will work only if the values of `s_dt$d` are the same for each `o` as in the MRE:

```
identical(s_dt$d, rep(s_dt[o == 1]$d, length.out = nrow(s_dt)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Now let's build the functions to accept `s_dt` and `c_dt`:

```
# slightly modified original function for comparison
fun1 <- function(dt, c_dt) {
  # don't use chaining here, for more useful profvis output
  dt <- dt[c_dt, on = .(d)]
  dt <- dt[, r := fcase(d == "c", t,
                        is.na(v), 0,
                        rep(TRUE, .N), v^t)]
  dt <- dt[, .(r = prod(r)), keyby = .(b, n)]
  dt <- dt[, .(r = sum(r)),  keyby = .(b)]
}

fun2 <- function(s_dt, c_dt, cl = NULL) {
  s_dt <- copy(s_dt)
  c_dt <- copy(c_dt)
  # preprocess to get "a", "tt", "i", and "idxs"
  i_dt <- s_dt[o == 1][, idxs := .I][c_dt, on = .(d)][, ic := .I][!is.na(v)]
  ub <- unique(c_dt$b)
  un <- unique(c_dt$n)
  nb <- length(ub)
  nn <- length(un)
  c_dt[, `:=`(i = match(n, un) + nn*(match(b, ub) - 1L), r = 0)]
  c_dt[, `:=`(i = i + (0:(.N - 1L))*nn*nb, ni = .N), i]
  c_dt[d == "c", r := t]
  a <- array(1, c(nn, nb, max(c_dt$ni)))
  a[c_dt$i] <- c_dt$r # 3-d array to store v^t (updated for each unique "o")
  i <- c_dt$i[i_dt$ic] # the indices of "a" to update (same for each unique "o")
  tt <- c_dt$t[i_dt$ic] # c_dt$t ordered for "a" (same for each unique "o")
  idxs <- i_dt$idxs # the indices to order s_dt$v (same for each unique "o")
  uo <- unique(s_dt$o)
  v <- collapse::gsplit(s_dt$v, s_dt$o)
  
  if (is.null(cl)) {
    # non-parallel solution
    data.table(
      o = rep(uo, each = length(ub)),
      b = rep(ub, length(v)),
      r = unlist(
        lapply(
          v,
          function(x) {
            a[i] <- x[idxs]^tt
            sumprod(a)
          }
        )
      ),
      key = "o"
    )
  } else {
    # parallel solution
    clusterExport(cl, c("a", "tt", "i", "idxs"), environment())
    
    data.table(
      o = rep(uo, each = length(ub)),
      b = rep(ub, length(v)),
      r = unlist(
        parLapply(
          cl,
          v,
          function(x) {
            a[i] <- x[idxs]^tt
            sumprod(a)
          }
        )
      ),
      key = "o"
    )
  }
}
```

Now the data:

```
# problem sizing ----
bigdims <- list(o = 50000, d = 50, b = 250, n = 200) # "big" problem - real-life size
lildims <- list(o =   100, d = 50, b =  25, n = 200) # "lil" problem (make runtime shorter as example)

# build some test data tables ----
build_s <- function(dims) {
  o <- seq_len(dims$o)
  d <- paste0("d",seq_len(dims$d))
  v <- as.double(seq_len(dims$o * dims$d))/10000
  CJ(o, d)[, `:=`(v = v)]
}

build_c <- function(dims) {
  b <- paste0("c", seq_len(dims$b))
  n <- seq_len(dims$n)
  d <- c("c", paste0("d", seq_len(dims$d)))
  t <- as.double(rep_len(0:6, dims$b * dims$n * (dims$d+1)))
  dt <- CJ(d, b, n)[, `:=`(t = t)]
  dt <- dt[t != 0]
}
```

Timing the lil problem, which is so small that parallelization doesn't help:

```
s_dt <- build_s(lildims)
c_dt <- build_c(lildims)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fun1 = s_dt[, fun1(.SD, c_dt), o],
                               fun2 = fun2(s_dt, c_dt),
                               times = 10,
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: seconds
#>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  fun1 3.204402 3.237741 3.383257 3.315450 3.404692 3.888289    10
#>  fun2 1.134680 1.138761 1.179907 1.179872 1.210293 1.259249    10
```

Now the big problem:

```
s_dt <- build_s(bigdims)
c_dt <- build_c(bigdims)

system.time(dt2p <- fun2(s_dt, c_dt, cl))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  24.937   9.386 330.600

stopCluster(cl)
```

A bit longer than 5 minutes with 31 cores.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you so much for the time you've spent breaking it down. I hadn't considered the armadillo at all for this, so that's particularly helpful. I can also use that in other bits of the code I'm writing.